# find top entries in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database each row has a column for average rating.

Now lets say I have thousands of rows with a variety of averages such as `4.45 4.78 3.21 2.13 4.91`

How would I get the rows with the top 3 highest average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order rows in descending  with `order by average_rating desc` and `limit` output to the top 3 results:

```
select average_rating
from tbl
order by average_rating desc
limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for TOP Clause:

> SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name LIMIT number;

```
SELECT *
FROM Table order by column  Desc
LIMIT 5;
```

or u can use

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Table;
```

but it will give you top 2 based on your primary key

Comment: Needs ORDER BY otherwise it will just get first 5 averages, not top

Answer (score 0):

Order the avg by `DESC` order to find largest avergaes and then `LIMIT 5` to find the top 5 avg

```
SELECT avg FROM table_name ORDER BY avg DESC LIMIT 5;
```